# android numpad on button click

Tags: android

How to show the android numpad on a button click,without using xml.
i know the code for showing simple keyboard that is:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
KeyboardMouse.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

But i want to show only numeric keypad instead.
Please help me.

Comment: You want to display keyboard for what?? For EditText?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8061484/1160207

Comment: No.. i want to change the keyboard mode... "from TextKB to numericKB and vice versa on a button click event.

Comment: Yes it is fine. but where do you want this input? In EditText or else?

Comment: But ultimately, you are going to show keyboard for EditText. Right??

Answer (score 2):

try the following code

```
    EditText ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editeextId);
ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: i am not sticking with edittext only...i want a seperate numpad that can be used anywhere same as simple keyboard works.

Comment: But ultimately, you are going to show keyboard for EditText. Right??

Comment: No..I am using it to write in notpad,wordpad also